# Appending an element based on choice from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create multiple fields based on a choice from a dropdown menu but when I choose from the options it only takes into account the first drop down menu, so if I create 3 fields with different values it will only take the first field 3 times

Here is the current function I'm using to work it

```
<button id="addInput">Add Another Field</button>

<div id="inputDiv">
    <p>
        <select id = "dropdown">
            <option value="null"></option>
            <option value="text">Text</option>
            <option value="note">Note</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
<div id="form"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#submit').live('click', function() {
  $("select").each(function() {
    if($('#dropdown').val() == "text"){
      $("#form").append('<input type="text"/>');
    }
    else if($('#dropdown').val() == "note"){
      $("#form").append('<textarea></textarea>');
    }
  });
});
```

And heres the fiddle I'm working on http://jsfiddle.net/me74Z/

Comment: You're using jQuery 1.8, [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated since 1.7 (replaced by [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle in several ways:

- use `$(this).val()` - that's the actual answer to your question
- use a class for `remInput` - you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same `id`
- use `on` instead of the deprecated `live`
- use a `switch` for readability
- use `closest` in the removal code, to make your code work if everything is wrapped in another `<p>`

http://jsfiddle.net/LucasTrz/me74Z/8/

```
$('#addInput').on('click', function() {
    $('#inputDiv').append('<p> <select> <option value="null"></option> <option value="text">Text</option> <option value="note">Note</option> </select> <button class="remInput">Remove</button> </p>');     
});

$(document).on('click', '.remInput', function() { 
    $(this).closest('p').remove();
});

$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    $("select").each(function() {
        switch($(this).val()) {
            case "text":
                $("#form").append('<input type="text"/>');
                break;
            case "note":
                $("#form").append('<textarea></textarea>');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice will definitely take your updates into consideration as I go forward

Answer (score 1):

You are using #dropdown, use $(this) instead.

Here is fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/me74Z/6/

Code :

```
$('#submit').live('click', function() {
$("select").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "text"){
        $("#form").append('<input type="text"/>');
    }
    else if($(this).val() == "note"){
        $("#form").append('<textarea></textarea>');
    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not selecting the current element in the loop. Try this

```
$('#submit').live('click', function() {
    $("select").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "text"){
            $("#form").append('<input type="text"/>');
        }
        else if($(this).val() == "note"){
            $("#form").append('<textarea></textarea>');
        }
    });
});
```

By replacing '#dropdown' with this the loop checks the val of the current element instead of the first.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're only checking the value of #dropdown. Use `this` instead:

```
if ($(this).val() == "text") {
    $("#form").append('<input type="text"/>');
} else if ($(this).val() == "note") {
    $("#form").append('<textarea></textarea>');
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/me74Z/5/)**

Note: as others have mentioned, it's time to use `.on()` instead of `.live()` as it was removed in jq 1.9.

Comment: @Popnoodles - Yes, however it wasn't removed until 1.9. Wanna explain why my fiddle works then?

Comment: @Popnoodles - No, it doesn't. Your own fiddle fails. Create three selects. Set them to different options and submit.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `this`. This way it is checking each iteration of the element and check it's own value (`this`) accordingly.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/me74Z/4/

```
$('#submit').live('click', function() {
    $("select").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "text"){
            $("#form").append('<input type="text"/>');
        }
        if($(this).val() == "note"){
            $("#form").append('<textarea>hell</textarea>');
        }
    });
});
```